# unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5680: server supports 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: postgresql, confluence, postgresql-10

I am running confluence 7.9.1 and postgres 10 but when we start only postgres container it doesn't throw below logs

```
unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5680: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
```

but when we start confluence with version 7.9.1 , postgres container will throw above logs.

Anyone know how we can resolve this since we tried PGGSSENCMODE=disable in env but it didnt help.

Regards,

Samurai

Comment: Are you running the latest bug fix release of v10?

Comment: Yes please show the logs with the exact postgresql version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved this by using new postgresql-42.2.18.jar which we replaced with postgresql-42.2.16.jar

suggested here : https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-60515?error=login_required&error_description=Login+required&state=14f30dda-a08b-4f9d-9841-ed77c8e91c79

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using postgresql-42.2.16.jar or prior and are looking to quiet this error without upgrading the JDBC jar, you can use the following option in the connection string - note case sensitivity:

```
gssEncMode=disable
```